# netbeans, can't deploy web project

Tags: java, spring, netbeans, jsf-2, project

Here's a (simple) project that should demonstrate spring mvc + jsf 2.
I just can't load it in Netbeans; i tried to create a new project, add the sources in the web directory. 
NB gives me an error: build-impl.xml:669: The module has not been deployed.
It seems that the ant script couldn't manage this project.
thanks
ps. I use netbeans 6.9.1
Here's the log:

```
init:
deps-module-jar:
deps-ear-jar:
deps-jar:
library-inclusion-in-archive:
library-inclusion-in-manifest:
compile:
compile-jsps:
In-place deployment at C:\Users\agostino\Documents\NetBeansProjects\201011-spring-web-flow-with-jsf\SpringWebFlow-JSF-One\build\web
Initializing...
deploy?path=C:\Users\agostino\Documents\NetBeansProjects\201011-spring-web-flow-with-jsf\SpringWebFlow-JSF-One\build\web&name=SpringWebFlow-JSF-One&force=true failed on GlassFish Server 3
C:\Users\agostino\Documents\NetBeansProjects\201011-spring-web-flow-with-jsf\SpringWebFlow-JSF-One\nbproject\build-impl.xml:669: The module has not been deployed.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Comment: Can you please add stacktrace here ?

Comment: It happens once in a blue moon with NB in web-app, that instead of pointing you to the error it complains about some line in build-impl.xml. You do not usually touch this file.

Comment: When it happens to me, i search my code and xml files thoroughly myself. You can also create a new project and refactor copy the code. Why don't you upgrade to Netbeans 7?

Comment: @Costis Aivalis. I'm going to try to refactor. I won't upgrate because my company manages platform upgrade all at the same time. First try to solve an issue. If can't, evaluate whether upgrading.

Answer (score 2):

check in the project directory if (Folder)META-INF->(file)context.xml exists.

Comment: no, it doesn't, and i've checked other working projects too, never seen this file.

Comment: Sorry for late reply...i think it also depends on the server which you are using. Select the tomcat server. I also faced this problem a while ago. Create a folder META-INF and then create context.xml file. Give the below lines in .xml file

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Context antiJARLocking="true" path="/YourProjectName"/>